# Django serializers nested data reformat

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a three model course_category,course and sub_course which have Foreign key relationship between them serially. I am using DRF serializer to pull a nested data where i want a course_category as my first parent and course as second and subcourse as child but it is totally opposite while i use prefetch_related().

```js
class course_categories(models.Model):
    deleted_flag = [('y', 'yes'), ('n', 'no')]
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted_flag = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=deleted_flag, default='n')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class courses(models.Model):
    deleted_flag = [('y', 'yes'), ('n', 'no')]
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    course_categories = models.ForeignKey(
        'course_categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted_flag = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=deleted_flag, default='n')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name


class subcourse(models.Model):
    deleted_flag = [('y', 'yes'), ('n', 'no')]
    subcourse_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    courses = models.ForeignKey(
        'courses', related_name="subcourse", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcourse_short_description = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted_flag = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=deleted_flag, default='n')
```

here is my models.py

and serializers here

```js
class CourseSerializerView(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # subcourse = SubcourseSerializerView()

    class Meta:
        model = courses
        fields = ('__all__')


class SubcourseSerializerView(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # courses = CourseSerializerView()

    class Meta:
        model = subcourse
        fields = ('__all__')
        depth = 2
```

and my views.py

```js
@api_view(['GET', ])
def get_course_tree_view(request):
    queryset = subcourse.objects.prefetch_related('courses')

    serializer = SubcourseSerializerView(queryset, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and here is my output

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subcourse_name": "Physics",
        "subcourse_short_description": "this is physics",
        "created_by": "narendra",
        "created_date": "2021-02-02T15:02:31.817562Z",
        "modified_by": null,
        "modified_date": null,
        "is_deleted_flag": "n",
        "courses": {
            "id": 1,
            "course_name": "Engineering Entrance Preparation",
            "created_by": "narendra",
            "created_date": "2021-01-22T13:43:01.436771Z",
            "modified_by": null,
            "modified_date": null,
            "is_deleted_flag": "n",
            "course_categories": {
                "id": 1,
                "category_name": "Entrance Preparation",
                "created_by": "narendra",
                "created_date": "2021-01-22T13:31:15.284123Z",
                "modified_by": null,
                "modified_date": null,
                "is_deleted_flag": "n"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "subcourse_name": "Chemistry",
        "subcourse_short_description": "this is chemistry",
        "created_by": "narendra",
        "created_date": "2021-02-02T15:02:52.023065Z",
        "modified_by": null,
        "modified_date": null,
        "is_deleted_flag": "n",
        "courses": {
            "id": 1,
            "course_name": "Engineering Entrance Preparation",
            "created_by": "narendra",
            "created_date": "2021-01-22T13:43:01.436771Z",
            "modified_by": null,
            "modified_date": null,
            "is_deleted_flag": "n",
            "course_categories": {
                "id": 1,
                "category_name": "Entrance Preparation",
                "created_by": "narendra",
                "created_date": "2021-01-22T13:31:15.284123Z",
                "modified_by": null,
                "modified_date": null,
                "is_deleted_flag": "n"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

but the output i want is just oppsite of the output i got

and i know queryset = subcourse.objects.prefetch_related('courses') is the one where i shall work on but i'm new at it i make the changes by shuffling courses and subcourse but it gives the errors that courses don't have subcourse objects

Comment: did answer worked on you? let me know in answer's comment :)

Comment: yes @daneilJames it worked, but should include many=True in both course and subcourse serializers. Thank You man :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once try this I am not sure but have a try once.

```
class SubCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    class Meta:
        model = subcourse
        fields = ('__all__')
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subcourse = SubCourseSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = course
        fields =('id','course_name','created_by','modified_by','modified_by','modified_date','is_deleted_flag','subcourse',)
```

and finally course_categories

```
class CourseCategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        course = CourseSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
            model = course_categories
            fields = ('id','category_name','created_by','created_date','modified_date','modified_by','is_deleted_flag','course',)
```

and class name in Python always starts with capital letter and we usally wont use '_' in word separataion like course_categories you should practice naming convention.. we use CourseCategories as class name.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in query you using course as reference to fetch all data.

```
fields = ('course',)
```

or you can do

in views.py

```
class ModelName_APIView(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        model_refrence = Article.objects.filter()
        serializer = Modle_Serializer(model_refrence,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```